# Firebase Auth creating users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can't seem to get this to work.  The database portion works and I'm getting user info as intended in the database, but it is not creating users in Firebase Auth.  For the following code, it printed "can't register."

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class AddUserTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!


@IBAction func saveUserButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: "pass", completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("Can't Register")
        }
        else {
            print ("I don't know what this means")
        }
    })

    ref?.child("Users").childByAutoId().setValue(["First Name": self.firstNameTextField.text, "Email": self.emailTextField.text])

}
```

Comment: If you print the value of `error`, it will probably tell you *why* the user can't be registered.

Answer (score 1):

Just include Firebase, you don't need to include FirebaseAuth as well on each page.

Here's my working code for FireBase login, I did this from a Youtube tutorial a few weeks ago.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var signinSelector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var signinLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signinButton: UIButton!

    var isSignIn:Bool = true


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func signinSelectorChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        //Flip the boolean true to false
        isSignIn = !isSignIn

        //Check the boolean and set the buttons and labels
        if isSignIn {
                signinLabel.text = "Sign In"
                signinButton.setTitle("Sign In", for: .normal)
        }
        else {
                signinLabel.text = "Register"
                signinButton.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func signinButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //Do some form validation on email and password
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text
        {

        //Check if it's signed or register

        if isSignIn {
            //Sign in the user with Firebase
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

                //Check that user isn't nil
                if let u = user {
                        //User is found, goto home screen
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
                }
                else{
                    //Error:  Check error and show message
                }
            })
        }

        else {
            //Register the user with Firebase

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

                //Check that user isn't NIL
                if let u = user {
                    //User is found, goto home screen
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    //Check error and show message
                }

            })



            }
    }


}

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //Dismiss the keyboard when the view is tapped on
        emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }


}
```